# "Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing" on (seemingly) simple code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Does anyone have an idea of why my code is throwing the "Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing" error? I've read that this is usually caused by a large dataset, but all the datasets involved here are tiny. For whatever reason, the error is being thrown on line 6. I'm new to both Apps Script and Javascript, but I don't think this code should take very long to run at all. The function simply aims to take values from one sheet and drop them into their corresponding place on another sheet -- I've used formulas in the sheet to find the column number (that is the column_nums var) although ideally I would find an all-script solution. The reason I'm doing this through script and not a simple index match is because I want the values from sheet A to be updated over time and use sheet B to periodically (on a trigger) paste in sheet A's values to track them over time. Apologies if this is a basic question, thanks so much!

```
function export_maxes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var new_maxes = source.getRange("E1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues();
  var column_nums = source.getRange("A1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues();

  // find row 
  var row_num = destination.getRange("B1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getHeight();
  var row_num = row_num + 1;

  // find columns and input maxes. start at 1 bc data has headers
  for (var i = 1; i < new_maxes.length; i++) {
    destination.getRange(row_num, column_nums[i]).setValue(new_maxes[i])
  } 

};
```

Comment: To help us visualize, could you share the spreadsheet or attach pictures of sample data?

Comment: Sure, thank you so much! I made a mockup of the problem.

Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hSGck_C1EOmPI9dFmDaBrLOrNJm_w_DrEM4Vn67-CtI/edit?usp=sharing

The "sold this week" corresponds to new_maxes; "lookup helper" to column_nums. As I said, including the lookup in a column is a somewhat ugly solution that I'd rather avoid by doing this search in script. The column headers in the second sheet contain all the values from product in the first sheet, but they are jumbled.

Comment: I just want to 1. get row number by finding length of data in the second sheet +1 2. find the column number through some sort of search, ideally in script, and 3. use this row and column information to paste in the appropriate value. Thanks a million!

Comment: Your code is working just fine. Have you tried another method like [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) instead of getDataRegoin()?

Comment: I apologize -- I see what the problem is now! In the actual sheet, I have the lookup columns grouped out. When I ungroup both of the lookup columns, it runs perfectly fine. Is there a way to allow this to run even when the lookup columns are grouped and closed? Apologies again for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing issue tracker for "[getDataRegion failed when it faces hidden rows or columns](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146868763)". Alternative solution is to show the hidden column groups by using `method:expandAllColumnGroups()` and hide the column after you fetched the data by using `method:collapseAllColumnGroups()`

Your code should look like this.

```
function export_maxes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];
  source.expandAllColumnGroups();
  var new_maxes = source.getRange("E1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues();
  var column_nums = source.getRange("A1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getValues();

  // find row 
  var row_num = destination.getRange("B1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getHeight();
  source.collapseAllColumnGroups();
  var row_num = row_num + 1;

  // find columns and input maxes. start at 1 bc data has headers
  for (var i = 1; i < new_maxes.length; i++) {
    destination.getRange(row_num, column_nums[i]).setValue(new_maxes[i])
  } 
};
```

### References:

[expandAllColumnGroups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#expandallcolumngroups)

[collapseAllColumnGroups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#collapseallcolumngroups)